# How do you get feedback on your portfolio?

Tags: feedback, portfolio, expert-review

What are the best ways to get useful and constructive feedback on your portfolio?

For example, a service such as [Evisors](http://www.evisors.com) will connect you with industry professionals for resume critiques, mock interviews, and career discussions.  You'll pay for the time of someone experienced in the field and in exchange, receive some very good feedback.

I'm looking for the ways other UX practitioners have gone about receiving feedback on their portfolio from those with experience hiring in the industry and the difference it made for them professionally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many great ways to get feedback on your portfolio **without paying.**

1. **Meetup.com** has many UX groups.
   http://goo.gl/LPz8Jp
   Making friends with similar interests is a great way to feedback. Even if you can't meet in person, joining groups like this is a good way to get involved in discussion and meet experts who can provide feedback.
2. **Interviews**. Go ahead and apply to random companies, even if you're not looking for a job yet. Show off your portfolio and experts will tell you what they think. When/if you are ever turned down, ask for the constructive criticism. Also, the practice is always good!
3. **Recruiters.** Find recruiters for the field on linkedin. They benefit when you are hired and have a lot of experience making portfolios and people's experience look good.

Answer (score 1):

UX meet ups - the easiest way to get to know professionals face to face, most of the time they are very helpful. Few of my friends got valuable feedback and one even got a job via UXPA meet up in London.

forums - find a UX forum and ask for help there

twitter - start a conversation with a UX professional that you admire.

These are just 3 easy ways to get professional feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Behance arrange some meetups for portfolio reviews. They can be quite helpful and free.

[Behance Reviews](http://www.behance.net/reviews)

[Meet Up Behance Reviews](http://www.meetup.com/BehanceReviews/)

I hope its helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can start with giving feedback to *other people* about *their* portfolios or websites/apps ... and then you'll get back feedback yourself, about *your* portfolio, about as much as you gave to others.

Here: https://usability.testing.exchange

Submit a link to your portfolio / website. Optionally, edit the questions and instructions to clarify that you want feedback about your portfolio, rather than about [the website that displays your portfolio].

(I'm developing Usability Testing Exchange.)